# Drawing position is changed in PrintPageEventArgs.Graphis

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, graphics, drawing

I’m working in WinForms project and I have the queries in Printing the text . So I have created the simple sample to test the issue.  In Form, I have drawn the string between two lines manually by using Form.Graphics and done the same again by using PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics in PrintDocument.PrintPage event. The drawing position is changed in print preview. Please see the below image , that show the issue(i.e drawing the lines is differed between Form.Graphics and PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics). Please let me know , why the drawing position is changed?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
}

void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), 10, 10, 10, 25);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Some Chars are getting Cut in Print Preview", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 10, 10);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), 228, 10, 228, 25);
}

void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), 10, 10, 10, 25);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Some Chars are getting Cut in Print Preview", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 10, 10);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), 228, 10, 228, 25);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    ppd.Document = doc;
    ppd.Document.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
    ppd.ShowDialog();
}
```

[image]

Sample: [TestSample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9MOGv1FOt-TWWVYeTZpUnEtTlE)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Hi , I can't use Graphics.MeasureStrings() in my production level. because each text in a column will have different length.

Comment: Then measure all the strings and take the max...

Comment: Side note: Using hard coded magic numbers is almost never what you want to do. And with dynamic strings it is definitely not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The positions aren't always going to be the same, please don't use magic numbers. Think about what would happen if you changed the font size?

Instead look into using [`Graphics.MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(theText, this.Font);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), stringSize.Width + 1, 10, stringSize.Width + 1, 25);
```

Also with this approach you can use the `stringSize.Height` to get the height of the string instead of hard coding `25`:

```
int lineEndY = 10 + stringSize.Height /* + anyBufferConstant*/;
```

Side Note: `Pen` and `SolidBrush` implement `IDisposable` probably best to wrap them in a using statement, but you can also use `Pens.Red` for this particular case. And you also duplicate code you could use a helper method. Putting this together:

```
private void DoPrintingLogic(Graphics g, string text)    
{
    const Point startPos = new Point(10, 10);

    SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(text, this.Font);

    using (SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Colors.Red))
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, startPos.X, startPos.Y, startPos.X, startPos.Y + stringSize.Height);
        g.DrawString(text, this.Font, redBrush, startPos.X, startPos.Y);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, startPos.X + stringSize.Width, startPos.Y, startPos.X + stringSize.Width, startPos.Y + stringSize.Height);
    }
}
```

---

<sub>**Disclaimer**: All code is untested.</sub>